# Using Google Drive API to get list of files

Tags: vb.net, list, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am trying to Return the list of files in my Google drive through the Google API. Everything works fine except it keeps returning a long list of *google.apis.drive.v2.data.file* instead of the actual files. It's probably something wrong in my code but i am not sure. Thanks for the help!

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim bob As New GoogleDrive
        Dim joe As New DriveModifyDate


        Dim items As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, joe.GetFiles(bob.service, ""))
        MsgBox(items)
```

I use that to call this piece of code.

```
 Public Function GetFiles(ByVal service As DriveService, ByVal search As String) As IList(Of File)
        Dim Files As IList(Of File) = New List(Of File)
        Try
            'List all of the files and directories for the current user.  
            Dim list As FilesResource.ListRequest = service.Files.List
            list.MaxResults = 1000
            If (Not (search) Is Nothing) Then
                list.Q = search
            End If
            Dim filesFeed As FileList = list.Execute
            '/ Loop through until we arrive at an empty page

            While (Not (filesFeed.Items) Is Nothing)
                ' Adding each item  to the list.
                For Each item As File In filesFeed.Items
                    Files.Add(item)
                Next
                ' We will know we are on the last page when the next page token is
                ' null.
                ' If this is the case, break.
                If (filesFeed.NextPageToken Is Nothing) Then
                    Exit While
                End If
                ' Prepare the next page of results
                list.PageToken = filesFeed.NextPageToken
                ' Execute and process the next page request
                filesFeed = list.Execute

            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' In the event there is an error with the request.
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return Files
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs: [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1File.html)

Your function returns a list of Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File which is absolute ok, if you need the filename of each you need to get the **OriginalFilename** property.

Answer (score 0):

[service.Files.List](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) returnes a response body, with in that body are items each item is a [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource).

To down load the file, you just need to take the downloadURL and read from it as a stream.

Something like this (Only example I can find is C#)

```
/// <summary>
  /// Download a file and return a string with its content.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="authenticator">
  /// Authenticator responsible for creating authorized web requests.
  /// </param>
  /// <param name="file">Drive File instance.</param>
  /// <returns>File's content if successful, null otherwise.</returns>
  public static System.IO.Stream DownloadFile(
      IAuthenticator authenticator, File file) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.DownloadUrl)) {
      try {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
            new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
        authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
          return response.GetResponseStream();
        } else {
          Console.WriteLine(
              "An error occurred: " + response.StatusDescription);
          return null;
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
      return null;
    }
  }
```

code ripped from [Files:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get)

Code in the sample [lib](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Google-Drive/Google-Drive-Api-dotnet/Google-Drive-Api-dotnet/DaimtoGoogleDriveHelper.cs) also C# sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To add to DalmTo's and David's answers, you need to be clear what you mean by "file". Generally the Drive nomenclature uses "File" to refer to the metadata such as title, parent folder, dateModified, etc. It uses the term "media" or "content" to refer to the file's content. So if you wish to download the content, it's a two stage process. Firstly get the ID's as you are doing (although I would suggest using fields= to limit the volume of meta data you fetch). Then for each ID, download the content using the downloadUrl, or exportLinks for non-Google and Google file types respectively. If it's just the file names that you want to list, just display the "title" property.